# nodejs version issue when installing express

Tags: node.js, express, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Just setting up my raspberry pi as node.js server. Did a clean install of Raspberian

then installed node

if I do node -v it says:
v0.10.25

then installed npm

if I do npm --version it says:
1.1.4

if I do then npm install express it fails and as the reason why it says

npm ERR! Required: {"node":">= 0.8.0"}
npm ERR! Actual:   {"npm":"1.1.4","node":"0.6.19"}

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bad intall of nodejs.

Try to:

**Remove nodejs:**

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs
```

**then, get the python-s-p package**:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

**Add add the chris-lea ppa:**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js

sudo apt-get update
```

**Finally, install again**

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

*Everything should work fine now.*

Comment: The chris-lea ppa only contains binaries for x86/x86-64, not ARM like the Pi has.

Comment: it should be up to date

Comment: I tried all of the above with no success. ended up ditching the pi and installing it on my mac mini. worked first time.

Answer (score 0):

I used this manual and version 0.11.3 and got success.
http://doctorbin.tumblr.com/post/53991508909/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-nodejs-npm-and