# Unable to install Express Node module on Raspberry Pi

Tags: node.js, express, npm, raspberry-pi

Newbie with raspberry and node here.

I have followed these [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697946/nodejs-version-issue-when-installing-express) to update nodejs on my raspberry pi running Raspbian, but when I check if the Express module is installed correctly (via the npm list command) I get the following (please excuse the special characters generated by copy-paste):

```
pi@cutiepi ~ $ npm list
/home/pi
âââ UNMET DEPENDENCY express *
âââ¬ socket.io@0.9.16
  âââ base64id@0.1.0
  âââ policyfile@0.0.4
  âââ redis@0.7.3
  âââ¬ socket.io-client@0.9.16
    âââ¬ active-x-obfuscator@0.0.1
    â âââ zeparser@0.0.5
    âââ uglify-js@1.2.5
    âââ¬ ws@0.4.31
    â âââ commander@0.6.1
    â âââ nan@0.3.2
    â âââ options@0.0.5
    â âââ tinycolor@0.0.1
    âââ xmlhttprequest@1.4.2

npm ERR! missing: express@*, required by undefined@undefined
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I've run these steps prior to the above, and each step looks successfully completed:

```
335  node -v

336  npm -v

337  nodejs -v

338  npm list

339  sudo apt-get purge nodejs

340  nodejs -v

341  which nodejs

342  sudo apt-get update

343  sudo apt-get install python-software-properties

344  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js

345  sudo apt-get update

346  sudo apt-get install nodejs

347  which nodejs

348  nodejs -v

349  sudo npm install express -g

350  which express

351  npm list
```

Looking for any advice how I can fix this problem.  Thank you in advance, please let me know if I can provide more info that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm install -g` installs the module globally, allowing you to use its exported command-line tools, if any.

To call into the module from code (to `require()` it), you need to install it locally, without `-g`.

To write a Node.js project, you should create your own `package.json` file that lists your dependencies, then run `npm install` to install them all locally.

Comment: Thanks SLaks, that fixed it.  I realize I have to familiarize myself with the npm options.